# RSA: decrypting short message with a different public key

Tags: encryption, rsa, public-key, cryptanalysis, decryption

I am having a hard time understanding what I have come across using RSA-textbook.

So I have:

- e = 3 as an exponent
- a VERY long public key N of 1991 bits (clearly useless trying to factor)
- a very short cryptogram of 403 bits

By doing `C^(1/3)` (because we have a short message compared to the public key), I found the message of 135 bits.

However, when I generate a new public key, therefore calculating a new exponent `d`, and use it to decrypt the cryptogram, I find the message also!

I used the standard decryption method on a Python code I found for RSA-textbook here: https://www.packetmania.net/en/2022/01/22/Python-Textbook-RSA/

Using that code, I do what looks like: `RSA(2048, 3).decrypt(C)`. I also noticed that the length for the public can be anywhere `> 136` with my cryptogram.

How come generating a completely new `N = pq` and subsequently `d` then doing `C^d mod N` gives me my message?

Comment: Welcome to [cryptography.se]. Your experiment is not repeatable, therefore cannot be resolved. High probably, you are still using the short message, so the cube-root attack still works. This is why RSA need a proper padding scheme!

Comment: Hint: detail what "we have a short message $M$ compared to the public key" exactly means; what it implies about textbook RSA encryption $M\mapsto M^e\bmod N$ w.r.t. raising to the $e$ non-modularly $M\mapsto M^e$; what $C\mapsto C^{1/e}$ is w.r.t. the later, and thus w.r.t. textbook RSA decryption $C\mapsto C^d\bmod N$. Then it will be clear why in the experiment of the last three paragraphs of the question, the same cause "short message" yields that same effect, coming down to the same equality but used in the reverse direction.